# Превратить рекурсию в цикл

Tags: javascript, циклы, рекурсия

Как превратить рекурсию (функция c) в цикл?

```
function c(i, count, tour){
    let result = 0;
    for (let j = i; j <= count; j+=i){
        if (tour-1) result+=c(j, count, tour-1);
        else result++;
    }
    return result;
}

var a = 6;
var b = 4;

console.log(c(1, a, b));
```

Comment: А ничего, что там уже в функции цикл, там и рекурсия и цикл, оу...

Comment: Наверное, стоит подробнее описать, для чего эта функция, что она делает.

Comment: @WalkMess в том и проблема, что рекурсия используется потому, что необходимое количество циклов неизвестно

Comment: @vsemozhebuty ищет количество последовательностей чисел до a, которые делят предыдущее число нацело. Эти последовательности размером b, 
К примеру, при 3 2 ответ будет 5, так как [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [2, 2] [3, 3]

Comment: @o_o Почему бы вам не воспользоваться современными фишками типа Метода flat() возвращает новый массив, в котором все элементы вложенных подмассивов были рекурсивно "подняты" на указанный уровень depth. Это будет сделано всего в одну строчку, без навороченных циклов и ваших рекурсий.

Comment: @WalkMess суть задания в том, чтобы решить всё руками, без применения подобного

Answer (score 1):

Дам наводку, рассписывать не стану. У вас рекусия целочисленная, т.е по факту вы пробегаетесь по 3х мерному массиву, собственно она и создает сложность в представлении поведении.

создаёте 3х мерный массив и заполняете в цикле по каждому измерению.

аналогия с факториалом у которого одно измерение f[0] = 1, f[1] = 1, ..... вы заполгяете массив до нужного вам.

Comment: И какие данные должны быть записаны в трёхмерном массиве?

Comment: @o_o значения с[1, 1, 1] = 1; c[1, 1, 2] = 1,  ...

Comment: примерно вроде как я суть понял, но всё же попрошу описать подробнее (привести пример)